# Cannot find the external Ip in the result when creating a new address using Google Cloud compute library

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am using google-cloud/compute library for nodejs
I want to create a static ip so I call
region.createAddress(addressName, callback)

The external ip is created and I see it in the console, however , the  result from the api doesn't contain the actual ip. I need to code to get the external ip that was used for the address I created.
Th result address only contains the id and name
what is the problem.
In the documentation there is supposed to be an address property containing the ip but its not there
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the [get()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/compute/latest/Address.html#get) method provided by the library:

```
const Compute = require('@google-cloud/compute');
const compute = new Compute();
const region = compute.region(<region>);
const address = region.address(<address_name>);

address.get().then(function(data) {
  console.log(data[1].address);
});
```

Comment: hi , I tried get(), it does not return the ip , it returns id, name, networkTier, addressType, kind. but I dont see any ip in the result.

Comment: I have no idea why this happens, I create the IP with regiona.createAddress successfully, then it might take a couple of minutes before the actual IP address will be picked out and assigned, then I use address.get method and can see the address in the result. Try updating library, also try to create address with [another method](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/compute/latest/Address.html#create) and see if something changes.

Answer (score 0):

after speaking with google support , seems that the ip is not available immediately and we need to wait a little. so suggested solution are several retries until address.getMetadata contains address property in the result (that will be the ip)